# how to get only values from query dict

Tags: django, django-models, django-orm

```py
if request.method == 'POST': 
        product=request.POST.get('product')
        upload_month = request.POST.get('upload_month') 
        un_month= Planning_quantity_data.objects.values('month').filter(product=product,upload_month=upload_month).distinct()
        print(un_month)
```

```
<QuerySet [{'month': 'Mar_22'}, {'month': 'Apr_22'}, {'month': 'May_22'}, {'month': 'Jun_22'}]>
```

I want to get only the values without key and store it in a new list in
`views.py` file:

```py
like newlist = ['Mar_22' , 'Apr_22', 'May_22','Jun_22']
```

while I am using

```py
  un_month1=list(un_month.values())
        print(un_month1)
```

It is showing like something this:

```
[{'id': 1, 'upload_month': 'Mar_22', 'product': 'MAE675', 'material_code': 'MAE675 (MEMU â OB) RCF', 'order_type': 'Onhand', 'BOM_CODE': '675MEMU', 'month': 'Mar_22', 'quantity': 3, 'po_value': '37/5', 'remarks': 'Qty in Rakes. 3-5 rakes partial qty dispatched', 'empid': None}, {'id': 2, 'upload_month': 'Mar_22', 'product': 'MAE675', 'material_code': 'MAE675 (MEMU â OB) RCF', 'order_type': 'Onhand', 'BOM_CODE': '675MEMU', 'month': 'Apr_22', 'quantity': 3, 'po_value': '37/5', 'remarks': 'Qty in Rakes. 3-5 rakes partial qty dispatched', 'empid': None}, {'id': 3, 'upload_month': 'Mar_22', 'product': 'MAE675', 'material_code': 'MAE675 (MEMU â OB) RCF', 'order_type': 'Onhand', 'BOM_CODE': '675MEMU', 'month': 'May_22', 'quantity': 3, 'po_value': '37/5', 'remarks': 'Qty in Rakes. 3-5 rakes partial qty dispatched', 'empid': None}]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use [**`values_list()`** <sup>[django-docs]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/models/querysets/#values-list) with a single field, you can use `flat=True` to return a `QuerySet` of single values, I mean:

```py
if request.method == 'POST':
    product=request.POST.get('product')
    upload_month = request.POST.get('upload_month') 
    newlist = list(Planning_quantity_data.objects.filter(product=product,upload_month=upload_month).values_list('month', flat=True))
    print(newlist)
```

And this will print just `['Mar_22', 'Apr_22', 'May_22', 'Jun_22']` for you.